# Opening Custom Page URL in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't seem to get a simple additional page opened in Wordpress. I have in my theme directory a file called *contact.php*. How do I get  tag to source this page? Ideally it'd look similar to the below:

```
<a href="<?php get_template_directory_uri('contact'); ?>"> Contact Us </a>
```

If i were to use Wordpress's Page setup I'd have a huge block of code similar to:

```
if (page == contact) {
    return contact form
} elseif (page == about) {
    return about me page
} else {
    return the regular page format.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following instead:

`<a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/contact.php'; ?>"> Contact Us </a>`